# Apply command to this area only

Tags: macros, block

What is the syntax for apply command on specific area only?

What I mean is something like:

```
\newcommand{\somevariable}{3}
\somevariable %3
-- some block which doesn't effect the outsize --
\renewcommand{\somevariable}{5}
\somevariable %5
-- end of the block --
\somevariable %3
```

I don't want to use `renewcommand` agian outside the block. 
Is there a way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: You should not (re)define `\number` to begin with: it's a fundamental primitive and redefining it can lead to very weird errors and definitely to failure.

Comment: It's just an example.. Call the command whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions with `\newcommand` (along with most settings, such as font settings other than latex counter settings) are local so scoped by andy brace group `{....}` or any environment `\begin{..} .... \end{..}`

This typesets 3 5 3

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\somevariable}{3}
\somevariable %3

{
\renewcommand{\somevariable}{5}
\somevariable %5
}

\somevariable %3

\end{document}
```